# Unable to connect to dynammo db from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have written a simple lambda function to list the tables on DynammoDb. But When i execute My code, I am unable to connect to the DB server . I am getting NetworkingError .
Below is the Code,

```
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
console.log("$$$$$$$$$second test$$$$$$$$$$")
//var src_bkt = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
//var src_key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
//console.log(src_bkt)


console.log("##########################################")

console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
region: 'us-east-1',
endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});


    dynamodb.listTables({Limit: 10}, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err.code);
      } else {
         console.log("Table names are ", data.TableNames);
      }
    });
};
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: I dont think when you connect to AWS DynamoDb, endpoint will be `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: I have provided the same

Comment: There should also be `KEY` and `SECRET`

Comment: i am trying to access through the lambda function . I have assigned a full administrator role to the lambda function . This arrangement should not require KEY and SECRET

Comment: Yes, You were right . The issue was with th eend point . I made the endpoint as dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and it got rsolved! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of documentClient like below,

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

And call 'listTables' with documentClient. Please find a sample code for PUT which shows how I am using documentClient,

```js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region: "REGION"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {   
    var table = "EmployeeDetails";

    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Item: {
            "Id" : event.Id,
            "FirstName": event.FirstName,
            "LastName": event.LastName,
            "Age": event.Age,
            "Gender": event.Gender
        }
    };

  
    docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            callback(null, "Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
        }
    });
   
};
```

If you are running in Lambda region is not mandatory but it will work with region as well.

The same code is in my GitHub as well - https://github.com/vnathv/DynamoDb-CRUD.git